# Ninject avoid use named bindings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have got this code.

```
foreach(device into xmlfile)
{
       var kdevice = kernel.Get(type, parameters.ToArray()) as IDevice;
       devices.Add(kdevice);
       kernel.Bind(type).ToConstant(kdevice).InSingletonScope().Named(kdevice.Name);
       if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseDevice)))
         kernel.Bind<BaseDevice>().ToConstant(kdevice as BaseDevice).InSingletonScope().Named(kdevice.Name);
}
```

My problem is that in next iteration, Kernel.Get is resolved with first binding, even if i am not asking for named binding, so it should create a new object.

I cannot use a late final binding because other devices may have a "refDevice" string parameter that should be resolved with a named bound device.

What should i do?

Comment: You need to give way more context. What are you trying to do and why. Give some samples of what you want to tie to what. Then someone will be able to assist with expressing that as Ninject `Bind` statements. Right now, you're mixing `Get`s with `Bind`s, which is never a good idea and can always be worked around.

Comment: I'd like to register multiple classes that implements my interfaces with a name, even if they are same.
Example

IDevice -> TestDevice named "D1"
IDevice -> VirtualDevice named "D2"
IDevice -> VirtualDevice named "D3"

in this way i'd like to get them in my code using costructor injection:
void ctor([Named("D3")]IDevice mydev){}

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid re-bindings like this.

A dependency injection container should separate Registering (declaring the bindings) from Resolving (getting an object).

If you need several objects that implement an interface, then implements a class with a method that returns that list, and making that class a dependency of the class than needs those objects is the way to go.

Comment: I did not full understand your final sentence.
Can you provide an example? Is there any framework that may help in this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var devices = xmlFile
    .Select( def => kernel.Get(def.Type, def.Parameters.ToArray())
    .ToArray();

foreach( var device in devices)
    kernel.Bind(device.GetType()).ToConstant(device).Named(device.Name);

foreach( var device in devices.OfType<BaseDevice>())
    kernel.Bind<BaseDevice>().ToConstant(device).Named(device.Name);
```

I think you should also definitely look at `Ninject.Extensions.Xml`

Comment: I cannot use your code snippet because bindings should be available as soon as possible. Is there no other way to get this?

Comment: @Vincenzo 'should be available as soon as possible' ... for what? You need to explain the interrelationships that make this so necessary in order that someone might explain a way to achieve a result. To be honest, I still have no idea what you're *actually* trying to do - it seems you've hidden your actual problem by trying to explain it simply in your question

Comment: I cannot use your solution because there may be other devices with a "refDevice" string parameter that should be resolved with a named device binding.

With your way, when asked, no device binding will be available!

Comment: You've baffled me. I have no idea what you're talking about - I'm either stupid or you need to be more explicit about what you mean/want and not assume that I know what you mean from your comment. What sort of dependencies? Do they need to be named? have you looked at the Xml extensions yet? Perhaps a question edit might get others to start guessing?

Comment: Ok you're right. I'm gonna completely rewrite question this night.